# json.load, JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, utf-8, decode

I am reading in a json.bz2 file.

The code

```
with open(full_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as the_file:    
    data = json.load(the_file)
```

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I tried searching on google for solutions, but none of them works.

Comment: You are not doing anything to uncompress it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to decode the compressed JSON directly.  You need to uncompress it first. Use the [bz2 package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html).  For example:

```
import json
import bz2

# ...

data = json.loads(bz2.BZ2File(full_filename).read().decode())
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I deal with bz2 format.